# Is there a cursor overwrite/overtype mode in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find any way to put the cursor into 'overwrite' mode - as in when you press the insert key and newly typed characters overwrite the existing characters inline. I haven't found any reference anywhere online to the omission or inclusion of such a feature in VS Code, but it seems to be a fairly commonly used feature. Does this exist?

Comment: How the heck did this get into production code with a broken INS key?

Comment: Please vote for feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1012

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I too was missing the overtype mode in Visual Studio Code, so I went ahead and wrote [an Overtype extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype) to add the behavior!

You can install it by opening the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and entering:

```
ext install overtype
```

***Update**: As of this writing (August 2022), VS Code still does not have overtype built in, and the original extension seems to be no longer maintained. There is a more up-to-date fork [here](https://github.com/DrMerfy/vscode-overtype).*

Comment: the one time I actually need this stupid button and I didn't hit it on accident....

Comment: another possibility can be to use another editor in the rare occasions overwrite is desired.

Comment: 4 years later it seems that @Adam Maras extension is in the catalog:
Name: Overtype
Id: adammaras.overtype
Description: Provides insert/overtype mode.
Version: 0.2.0
Publisher: Adam Maras
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype

Comment: The original extension seems to be abandoned. Here is a fork with several updates: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DrMerfy.overtype

Comment: Ok, got the CTRL-SHIFT-P on Windows to open that pallete command - or View->Command Pallete

Comment: @warath-coder - It's 2023...it STILL isn't part of VS Code, which is why I'm here. For VS Code being the most state-of-the-art text editor out there, it fails at the basics of certain things, this inclusive. 
The find/replace function is also one of the worst I've ever seen in any text editor.

Comment: Please notice (at least) the updated fork also overwrites the `ctrl+shift-I` keybinding from 'Format Document' to 'Toggle Insert/Overwrite'

Answer (score 14):

For me, I think it's because of an extension called Vim (Vim emulation for Visual Studio Code). I was tired of this problem. Just going through all the extensions and settings, Finally I found this solution. By uninstalling this Vim extension I was free of this error.

[image: 1]

Comment: Vim (Vim emulation for Visual Studio Code) extension name.

Comment: I don't have Vim. I have that lack of overwrite.

Comment: I don't have this extension installed and I still have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working fine for me both ways I can switch it with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on latest VS Code and macOS system.

Comment: I don't understand, `shift+i` just types a capital `I`. How does it change insert/overwrite/overtype mode?

Comment: Is this when using VSCode like Vim or something? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do is highlight the text I want to replace with the mouse and then start typing. It sorta works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34765190)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not built in to VS Code at the time of this writing. If you want it to be, you should give a thumbs up to the relevant feature-request: [Insert key doesn't switch to overtype/overwrite mode #1012](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1012), which will increase its prioritization. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump". It's pretty high in the prioritization list (going by thumbs up reactions, at the time of this writing, it's #26, so keep the thumbs-ups coming and wait patiently).

As others have mentioned, you can install an extension which enables such behaviour, such as the [`adammaras.overtype`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype) extension, or its more up-to-date fork, [`DrMerfy.overtype`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DrMerfy.overtype) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with these extensions)</sub></sup>. Note that it purportedly has issues with non-ASCII characters ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1012#issuecomment-768741413)).

Useless note: There's also an issue ticket for this in the monaco repo: [overwrite mode #86671](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86671), but it's closed to track the discussion in the corresponding VS Code issue ticket (I *told* you this note was useless). Somewhat less useless note: If you're building something with monaco, You might want to see [this comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1012#issuecomment-1585592567).

Answer (score -3):

You can follow these steps:

1. Open the *Extensions view in Visual Studio Code* by clicking on the Extensions icon on the left-hand side of the editor or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ (Mac).
2. Search for *"Vim"* in the search bar.
3. Click on the gear icon next to the "Vim" extension and select *"Disable"* from the dropdown menu.