# VS Code cursor keep going into overtype mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code automatically changes to overtype mode at random times (ie. when I switch files or sometimes when I move cursor to another line). And I have to keep pressing the insert button to disable the overtype mode.

How do I permanently disable overtype mode?

Comment: This question needs more information. VS Code [doesn't have overtype built in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36165756/95852), so it almost certainly has to be due to some extension. The [one current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72617523/95852) is a good guess.

Answer (score 6):

Please try to uninstall VIM extensions if any and check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are functions default in your setting sections, but also some extensions can cause this issues.

Disable VIM extensions if you are not using them, is a big headache otherwise

Comment: This answer was already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72617523/6951294)